# Create UIImage of whole UICollectionView content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView.  No caching as I haven't needed to apply so far, only have sum of 7 different images, but possibly 40 cells.  I am also not experienced in that method.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *collectionImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
UILabel *ballLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
UILabel *ballLabelInfo = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:110];

ballShot *selectedBall = [self.statsView.visitBallShotCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *ballDetail;
NSString *labelInfo;



ballDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Foul"];
labelInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[selectedBall getFoulTypeText:selectedBall.foulid]];

collectionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedBall.imageNameLarge];
ballLabel.text = ballDetail;
ballLabelInfo.text = labelInfo;


return cell;
}
```

I am able to save displayed content of UICollectionView with even the correct content size, but not whole content.

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionBreakView
{
CGSize widthHeight = CGSizeMake(collectionBreakView.contentSize.width, collectionBreakView.contentSize.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(widthHeight, collectionBreakView.opaque, 0.0);
[collectionBreakView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return img;
}
```

How can I obtain whole content and place into the UIImage?  If caching is the answer can somebody please give me a starter in setting that up? 
Thanks in advance.